# react native react-navigation-tabs createMaterialTopTabNavigator animationEnabled no longer working

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I've recently updated react-navigation to 3.0.8 and added react-navigation-tabs, animationEnabled looks like its been dropped from createMaterialTopTabNavigator. Is there a work around to stop the animation?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `timingConfig` instead which configures the timing animation:

```js
const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  // screens
}, {
  timingConfig: { duration: 0 }
});
```

Comment: That answer stops the animation, but it has a sideffect that the tabs wont change after clicking on one

Comment: sounds like a bug. open an issue?